# Jetpack compose design like twitter header

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose

How can we achieve this kind of layout in jetpack compose?

I am interested in positioning the round picture 'GD', on top of the header image like it is here. I tried to use Box layout like this

```
Box(
modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .fillMaxHeight()
) {
Column(){
    Coil(
        modifier = Modifier
                    .fillMaxWidth()
                    .height(200.dp),
        
    )
}

Coil(
    modifier = Modifier
                .height(120.dp)
                .width(120.dp)
                .padding(top = 140.dp, start = 20.dp)
                .clip(CircleShape),
                
    contentScale = COntentScale.Crop
)


}
```

but this is not taking correct shape.
[image]

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: You can use a Box

Comment: I just edited it with my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `Box`.
Align the circular in the Box with the `align(BottomStart)` modifier and then apply an `offset` and finally clip the `Image` in a `CircleShape`.

Something like:

```
Box(Modifier.padding(top=40.dp)){
    Image(
        painterResource(/* ... */ ),
        "contentDescription",
    )
    Image(
        painter = rememberImagePainter("...."),
        modifier = Modifier
            .height(50.dp)
            .width(50.dp)
            .align(BottomStart)    //align in the Box
            .offset(12.dp, 25.dp)  //apply an offset
            .clip(CircleShape)     //clip the image
            .border(color= White, shape = CircleShape, width=  2.dp),
        contentDescription = "",
        contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
    )
```

Note: `rememberImagePainter` requires the [`coil-compose`](https://coil-kt.github.io/coil/compose/#jetpack-compose) implementation.

[image]